# Como verificar se uma sessão existe (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Tenho a seguinte função na minha `Controller`:

```
private function SetImageAndColor($client_id) {
    if (isset($_GET['color']) AND isset($_GET['image'])) {
        $dados['click2call'][$client_id]['image'] = $this->input->get('image');
        $dados['click2call'][$client_id]['color'] = $this->input->get('color');
        $this->session->set_userdata('click2call', $dados);
    }
}
```

Ela pega os parâmetros passados via `$_GET` e salva na sessão.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte: como faço para verificar se essa sessão existe, mas dentro da `View`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar se existe valores na sessão:

Exemplo:

```
// index_view.php
<html>
...
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('color') == 'blue') echo 'do_something'; ?>
...
</html>
```

Contudo, não cheguei a utilizar no CI essa estrutura para setar valores na sessão: 
Para seu caso, faria da seguinte forma, na que consta no manual do Codeigniter:

```
<?php 
    //controller.php    

    ...

    $image = $this->input->get('image');
    $color = $this->input->get('color');
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('nome' => 'click2call', 'id' => $cliente_id, 'image' => $image, 'color' => $color));
```

Comment: Valeu,cara! Resolveu!